# Finding .emacs file Fedora 20

Tags: linux, emacs24, fedora20

Using Fedora 20 with Emacs installed using

```
yum install emacs
```

I'm unable to find the .emacs file. I've referenced the Gnu [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init) and the file doesn't exist under any of the names provided.

Could you please tell me how to find the `.emacs` file and why it's not located in the usual ~/.emacs ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~/.emacs is for your own, personal configuration. You must create it yourself. (If you like, you can create ~/.emacs.d/init.el instead.)